# How can I append the very first line of a .txt file using C?

Tags: c

I have a program where I am trying to add wind data to a .txt file, but I am facing the issue where I add data, I close the program, try to add data again, and it eliminates the rest of the data. The following is an example of the .txt file:

```
3
3.60000 N
4.30000 E
5.40000 S
```

The first line is the number of data entries and the following are each wind speed and then wind direction.

My code works fine if I just add the data once and be done with it, but not if I want to add more work to what I previously did. I know I can use append to add data to the end, but it will not update the counter at the top. I want to be able to add data and also update the counter at the top. I need the counter for other functions in the code. The following is my code for the problem:

```
void addWindData(FILE* outFile, int numNumbers, double windSpd[], char windDir[]){
    int numItems;
    
    printf("How many data items would you like to add? ");
    scanf("%d", &numItems);

    fprintf(outFile, "%d \n", numItems);

    for(int i = 0; i < numItems; i++){
        printf("Wind speed? ");
        scanf("%lf", &windSpeed[i]);

        printf("Wind direction? ");
        scanf(" %c", &windDir[i]);

        fprintf(outFile, "%lf %c \n", windSpd[i], windDir[i]);
    }
}
```

I call the function as so:

```
fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w");
if(fp == NULL){
    printf("File could not be found! \n");
}
else{
    addWindData(fp, numNumbers, windSpd, windDir);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Any help I could get will be greatly appreciated. I understand that 'w' will always write, but when I use append, it starts a new count at the end and then adds the data. I just need help to figure out how to update the counter! I am very new to the C programming language and am still doing my best to learn. I am trying my best to use logic and reasoning, so it helps me to get inspiration from others! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Use `fopen(..., "a")` to append new data at end of the file.

Comment: I know how to append new data at the end of the file, I am asking how to update the counter at the top

Comment: *"I just need help to figure out how to update the counter!"*  The problem is that there's no way to insert a character into an existing file. So when the count changes from 9 to 10, there's no way to update the counter except to create a whole new file.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. You can reserve, say, 10 digits at the start of the file for the counter (for example "0000000315") and update the counter using `"r+"` mode and `sprintf(..., "%010d", ...)` or so.

Comment: Or keep the counter in a separate file.

Comment: Your program could do the following: 1. rename the existing file. 2. write the updated file. 3. delete the renamed file. This avoids the problem of what happens if your program gets interrupted between adding new records and updating the counter.

Answer (score 0):

File is open as stream, so you have 2 choices: Change chars or rewrite all file. You must know that you can change only existing chars! As [fopen reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) says to change chars you can use "r+" mode. This mode allow to read/write, starts from beginning and allows to [rewind](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/rewind).

Answer (score 0):

you can change `fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "w")` to `fp = fopen(FILE_NAME, "r+")` because w mode will erase the previous text in .txt file but r+ do not because r is upgrade mode.